# Extend API V1/products to put the not available products at the end

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, plugin, stock

I want to display out of stock products at the end of the V1/products response.

So far I tried to create a plugin on Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface to override the getList method but it doesn't work.

I don't know if this is a good method or I have to use an Observer or a plugin on another Class

I tried this in a di.xml file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="products-list" type="Custom\Api\Plugin\ProductList"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

And in ProductList.php :

```php
<?php

namespace Custom\Api\Plugin;

class ProductGet
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
    {
        // this method isn't called :(
    }
}
```

**Update #1**
I added a beforeGetList function :

```php
public function beforeGetList(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $subject,
        SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
    ) {
        $sortOrders = $searchCriteria->getSortOrders() ?? array();
        $sortOrders[] = $this->sortOrderBuilder->setField('stock_status')->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_DESC)->create();
        $searchCriteria->setSortOrders($sortOrders);
        return [$searchCriteria];
    }
```

Comment: Hey @darkmatterantearth, welcome! I'd like to recommend you to share more details about what you did so far. SO, generally speaking, is not here to do the work for you but try to help with specific issues based on your own work (code and/or research). You may want to refer to https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/ aswell to find some inforation how you may improve your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added some details. I'm not looking for a ready-made solution, but for ways to find the best way to do it.

Comment: Per your code example I guess there is some misinterpretation about what plugins are: "[Plugins] allow[s] you to substitute or extend the behavior of original, public methods for any class or interface" (see also https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html). That being said, instead of 'redefining' `getList()` you would want to have a method such as `beforeGetList`, `afterGetList` or `aroundGetList`. Also, `class ProductGet` should probably be `class ProductList`; In core Magento you should be able to find a few examples on existing plugins for this class already.

Comment: Thanks. I added a beforeGetList function (see update #1)
But stock_status isn't in the fields of the collection. How can I add a field with $collection->joinField ? Maybe with aroundGetList ?